# Angular Material mat-chips not setting to be removable

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

**Problem Statement**

My problem is that when I am using Angular Material's `mat-chip`, it seems it cannot be set as removable even though I set it to true.

---

**Code**

```
<mat-form-field>
 <input matInput [matChipInputFor]="chipList" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addOption($event)"
type="number" maxlength="4" placeholder="Enter an amount here">
 </mat-form-field>

<mat-chip-list>
<mat-chip #chipList *ngFor="let option of options" [removable]="true"
(removed)="removeOption(option)">{{option}}
</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

**RemoveOption Method**

```
removeOption(option: String) {
    const index = this.options.indexOf(option);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.options.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

---

**Explanation of Code**

As you can see, I have set `[removable]` to true and `(removed)` with a `removeOption` method. These things do not work for some strange reason.

I copied the example from here: https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples, the section with the example is named: "Chips with Input"

---

**Actual Output**

The chips show no little remove button on the right:

[image]

---

**Expected Output**

The chips with a little remove button on the right:

[image]

Comment: What is the code of your removeOption function?

Comment: Very nice structured question. Like it

Comment: Thank you for your compliment @LingVu. Thank you all for your effort!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to add the `mat-icon` to trigger the removal. In the material example you have:

```
   <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let fruit of fruits"
      [selectable]="selectable"
      [removable]="removable"
      (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
```

This contains the action to trigger `matChipRemove` inside the `mat-icon`.

Link for demo: https://stackblitz.com/angular/mjygopomxvq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.html

Comment: Thank you for your explained answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're not able to see the icon because the section `<mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>` is missing from the code.

Your code should look like this:

```
<mat-chip-list>
<mat-chip #chipList *ngFor="let option of options" [removable]="true"
(removed)="removeOption(option)">{{option}}
<mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Comment: maybe you should explain what you changed: the mat-icon to remove the chip, connected to the chip by matChipRemove.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the icon tag.

```
<mat-chip-list>
<mat-chip #chipList *ngFor="let option of options" [removable]="true"
(removed)="removeOption(option)">{{option}}
<mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that if the mat-icon or any other element that does matChipRemove has style "pointer-events: none;" then click on the mat-icon (X) doesn't remove the chip. The chip still can be removed by the keyboard backspace button. Solution - set "pointer-events: auto;"

Answer (score 1):

If even after having incorporated the remove icon you still can't see the remove button as happened to me, then, after having implemented all the previous recommendations, make sure that in the module of your component you have imported these four modules:

```
MatChipGrid,
MatChipRow,
MatChipInput,
MatChipRemove,
```

But specifically, the one referring to the remove button is: MatChipRemove.
This is the import you should add:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MyComponent} from "./my.component";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {MatButtonModule} from "@angular/material/button";
import {MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import {MatInputModule} from "@angular/material/input";
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {MatIconModule} from "@angular/material/icon";
import {MatChipGrid, MatChipInput, MatChipRemove, MatChipRow} from "@angular/material/chips";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatChipGrid,
    MatChipRow,
    MatChipInput,
    MatChipRemove,
  ], exports: [MyComponent]
})
export class MyModule { }
```